# Adding some mesh to existing rigged mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I have done rigged mesh with maked animation. Now, I have to add some mesh (new part of character) to the finalized rigged character. Can you please help me? :) I tryied find solution, tried "everything" and nothing help me, becouse the new part not corespond weight painted character. And when I reset all and maked new parent with aumotatic weight paint everything is absolutely wrong... :(

Thank you.

Robert.

Answer (score 0):

There is a data transfer modifier, which can transfer the weights between meshes. Depending on the meshes you might need to go in and change some things manually afterwards, but it sure takes care of most of it.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html

I would go with the Nearest Vertex sampling method. Topology option would not make sense in your case as the topologies are different.

The meshes should be joined after the data transfer modifier is added and applied

Comment: The data transfer modifier requires both meshes to be in exactly the same position before it will work. Telling someone to use the modifier without explaining this is setting them up for a fall, because no one would assume the need for this step if they didn't already know to expect it. Also, it's not clear how transferring weights would help someone who is combining a mesh that has no weights with another mesh that does have weights. There are no weights to transfer in this case: The new mesh isn't identical to the old, but is an extension of it. The whole armature will have to be rebound.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. The data transfer modifier uses different sampling methods to transfer the weights. 'Nearest vertex' for example does not require anything to be in the same position.

To clarify the data transfer modifier should be applied before combining the meshes. Then the weights will be merged and there should be not problem.

It is a common technique in rigging to attach things to an already skinned object like clothes and such.